# Sublime - ignore pep257 D100 warning?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimelinter, pep

I was searching for how to ignore specific warnings, but can't find exactly how to disable it.

I tried this (in SublimeLinter settings):

```
        "flake8": {
            "@disable": false,
            "args": [],
            "builtins": "",
            "excludes": [],
            "executable": "",
            "ignore": "D100",
            "jobs": "1",
            "max-complexity": 10,
            "max-line-length": null,
            "select": "",
            "show-code": false
        },
```

Then this:

```
        "pep257": {
            "@disable": false,
            "add-ignore": "",
            "args": [],
            "excludes": [],
            "ignore": "D100"
        },
```

And this:

```
        "pep257_ignore": [
            "D100"
        ],
```

But I still get that warning. So where should I disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `pep257` was renamed to `pydocstyle`, I am writing answer how to ignore error/warning for `pydocstyle`.

It seems previous way to specify configuration of sublime linter (e.g. ignore some errors/warnings) was bad practice and it is no longer supported (on newer versions) And it is now intended to use configuration files outside sublime itself.

`pydocstyle` documentation says that you need to provide configuration file where you can provide errors list to ignore, like (`setup.cfg` name can be used):

```
[pydocstyle]
ignore = D100
```

Though currently it still won't work, because `sublimelinter-pydocstyle` does not scan files in hierarchy if it is not specified explicitly in sublimelinter or project settings (https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-pydocstyle/issues/24#issuecomment-412329010)

So you need to specify path to your file, like (e.g. in sublime linter settings):

```
{
    "linters": {
        "pydocstyle": {
            "config": "/your/path/to/setup.cfg"
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. Do note, that for example flake8 sublime linter does not need to specify config path, it is scanned upwards and used if one is found (like if you put `setup.cfg` in some parent folder).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a short guide for ignoring Sublime Linter errors here: https://hightower.space/thoughts/sublime-linter-ignore-guide/.

The basic gist is that your Sublime Linter settings (available at *Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter > Settings*) should look something like:

```
// SublimeLinter Settings - User
{
    "lint_mode": "load_save",
    "linters": {
        "pydocstyle": {
            "ignore": "D100,D101,D102,D103,D104,D105",
        },
        "pep8": {
            "ignore": "E501"
        },
        "flake8": {
            "args": ["--ignore=E501"],
        }
    }
}]
```

There is more explanation in my [guide](https://hightower.space/thoughts/sublime-linter-ignore-guide/), but this gives the basic idea. Under the `"linters"` key you can give the name of a specific linter and the settings you would like to apply to that linter. As @Andrius pointed out, the `pep257` package was renamed to `pydocstyle`.